# Is it possible to get the KVC-String from Swift 4 KeyPath?

Tags: swift

For a project I am currently working on, it would be very useful to get the KVC-String from a KeyPath instance my method is receiving. Short example:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
}

let propertyCache = ["name": "something"]

func method<T>(_ keypath: KeyPath<Person, T>) -> T? {
    let kvcName = keypath.kvc
    return propertyCache[kvcName]
}
```

This might seem not very useful, but in my project it is :) I found a property on KeyPath called `_kvcKeyPathString` which is also public, but it returns `nil` every time I tried.
Or is their maybe a possibility to use reflection there? Thanks in advance for ideas/solutions!

Comment: `_kvcKeyPathString` will have a value if you mark the property with `@objc` since it exists to support interoperability.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! But it's not an option in my case :/ It seems like I'm not the only one with a use case: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5821

Comment: The Swift proposal for the KeyPath feature mentions the ability to build KeyPath's at runtime via strings in the future, so maybe at that time we'll be able to get the string value, or when they decide to give us some respectable reflection capabilities.

Comment: I hope that we get some more reflection features, not only in terms of keypaths. Thanks again for you answer, even if it doesn't solve my problem, the @objc attribute is correct. Could you please create an official answer that I can accept? Would then be better to find for others later on.

Comment: What I want is to go the other way: I have a string (from parsing XML), and I want to turn that into a Swift 4 keypath so that I don't have to use Cocoa KVC. For example `"firstName"` should be somehow transformed to `\Person.firstName`.

Comment: @matt that’s also a valid use case! But it’s also not possible currently afaik :/

Comment: I fear you're right. It's a pity, because there really are legitimate times when what you get is a string and you'd like to map that to a property. I'd like to give up Cocoa KVC, but it does that and Swift KeyPath doesn't.

Comment: "Expose API to retrieve string representation of KeyPath" - https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5220

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know of a pure Swift way to get the name of the property as a string yet.

But, if you add the `@objc` attribute to the property then `_kvcKeyPathString` will actually have a value instead of always being nil. Also, since Swift structs can't be represented in Objective-C, this method only works for classes.

A minimal working example usage:

```
class SomeClass {
    @objc var someProperty = 5
}

let keyPath = \SomeClass.someProperty
print(keyPath._kvcKeyPathString)
```

Comment: Do you know if using this property count as using a private API? Just wondering whether it would be a significantly bad idea to use this in an published iOS app (aside from the maintainability issues of course)

Comment: @AndrewBennet It's not a private API, it's just undocumented in the official Apple docs, therefore it is subject to change without any kind of notice. Their use of a leading underscore suggests that they don't really want people using it, but they could've marked it private with a bit more effort I'd imagine. [source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a49f175b0785477bff3abf47aff110e37d52f19f/stdlib/public/core/KeyPath.swift#L108)

Comment: Thanks! I may use it, and write a unit test to protect me from behavior changes 

Comment: @Allen Humphreys Can you write an example code? I tried but cannot get with Swift 4.1