# Getting string from Swift 4 new key path syntax?

Tags: swift, reflection, swift4, key-value-coding

How can you get a *string value* from [*Swift 4 smart keypaths*](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md) syntax (e.g., `\Foo.bar`)? At this point I'm curious about any way at all, does not matter if it's complicated.

I like the idea of type information being associated with smart key path. But not all APIs and 3rd parties are there yet.

There's old way of getting string for property name with compile-time validation by `#keyPath()`. With Swift 4 to use `#keyPath()` you have to declare a property as `@objc`, which is something I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: "Expose API to retrieve string representation of KeyPath": https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5220

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For Objective-C properties on Objective-C classes, you can use the [`_kvcKeyPathString` property](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2844583d7f9d51ce5c4da7776e19f0aab6f2e3f6/stdlib/public/core/KeyPath.swift#L107) to get it.

However, Swift key paths may not have String equivalents. It is a stated objective of Swift key paths that they do not require field names to be included in the executable. It's possible that a key path could be represented as a sequence of offsets of fields to get, or closures to call on an object.

Of course, this directly conflicts with your own objective of avoiding to declare properties `@objc`. I believe that there is no built-in facility to do what you want to do.

Comment: Nice catch! I did a quick test here and, unfortunately, it looks like the aforementioned `_kvcKeyPathString` property will *only* return non-nil values for `@objc` exposed properties. For instance, both `name` and `email` key paths, in my answer above, returned in `nil`.

Comment: Note from a related question: >> *But, if you add the `@objc` attribute to the property then `_kvcKeyPathString` will actually have a value instead of always being `nil`.* <<

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143292/is-it-possible-to-get-the-kvc-string-from-swift-4-keypath

Answer (score 54):

A bit late to the party, but I've stumbled upon a way of getting a key path string from `NSObject` subclasses at least:

```
NSExpression(forKeyPath: \UIView.bounds).keyPath
```

Comment: Nice idea, though I get a crash when running this in swift REPL
```import Foundation; class AClass: NSObject { var aValue: Int! }; NSExpression(forKeyPath: \AClass.aValue).keyPath```

Comment: @DannieP I think that would be because your property is of `Int!` type, which is an optional integer which cannot be exposed to Objective C. An `Int` type would probably work though.

Comment: I've just tried and it's pretty much the same for 'Int' and 'NSNumber".

Comment: @DannieP You need to expose the property to Objective-C using `@objc`. I tested your sample code (using a non-optional `Int`) in a Swift Playground and it worked just fine after doing that ;)

Comment: And that's something I'd still prefer to avoid. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This seems to crash when `_kvcKeyPathString` is nil, but at least it is a non-`_underscoreFunction` alternative in the public API.

Answer (score 36):

Short answer: you can't. The [`KeyPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keypath) abstraction is designed to encapsulate a potentially nested property *key path* from a given root type. As such, exporting a single `String` value might not make sense in the general case.

For instance, should the hypothetically exported string be interpreted as a property of the *root type* or a member of one of its nested types? At the very least a string array-ish would need to be exported to address such scenarios...

**Per type workaround**. Having said that, given that `KeyPath` conforms to the `Equatable` protocol, you can provide a custom, *per type* solution yourself. For instance:

```swift
struct Auth {
    var email: String
    var password: String
}
struct User {
    var name: String
    var auth: Auth
}
```

provide an *extension* for `User`-based key paths:

```swift
extension PartialKeyPath where Root == User {
    var stringValue: String {
        switch self {
        case \User.name: return "name"
        case \User.auth: return "auth"
        case \User.auth.email: return "auth.email"
        case \User.auth.password: return "auth.password"
        default: fatalError("Unexpected key path")
    }
}
```

usage:

```swift
let name:  KeyPath<User, String> = \User.name
let email: KeyPath<User, String> = \User.auth.email
print(name.stringValue)  /* name */
print(email.stringValue) /* auth.email */
```

I wouldn't really recommend this solution for production code, given the somewhat high maintenance, etc. But since you were curious this, at least, gives you a way forward ;)

Comment: How about using Mirror.Children (get a Child) to recursive printing a path using dot notation. What i cant believe is that mirror and KeyPath dont work with each other... what a missed opportunity on apple behalf.

Comment: @RicardoDuarte `Mirror` is a black-box, and nothing is guaranteed about its return value. Therefore, if you involve `Mirror` in your logic, your logic can break later if Apple changes `Mirror` implementation, and such breakage would be very very hard to fix if happens because direction of changes is unpredictable.

Comment: you can use sourcery to generate this boilplates. it is easy to maintain

Answer (score 23):

Expanding on [@Andy Heard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51376768/2177402) we could extend `KeyPath` to have a computed property, like this:

```
extension KeyPath where Root: NSObject {
    var stringValue: String {
        NSExpression(forKeyPath: self).keyPath
    }
}

// Usage
let stringValue = (\Foo.bar).stringValue
print(stringValue) // prints "bar"
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do this recently and I wanted to ensure that I get a static type check from the compiler without hardcoding the property name.

If your property is exposed to Objective-C(i.e @objc), you can use the `#keyPath` string expression. For example, you can do the following:

```
#keyPath(Foo.bar)
#keyPath(CALayer.postion)
```

See [Docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html)

Answer (score 3):

Quite late to the party, but this was my solution in Swift:

```swift
extension PartialKeyPath {
    var keyPath: String {
        let me = String(describing: self)
        let rootName =  String(describing: Root.self)
        let removingRootName = me.components(separatedBy: rootName)
        var keyPathValue = removingRootName.last ?? ""
        if keyPathValue.first == "." { keyPathValue.removeFirst() }
        return keyPathValue
    }
}
```

Alternatively, since I believe `String(describing: KeyPath)` always structures the string as `"\RootName.keyPathName"`, you could use dropFirst instead:

```swift
extension PartialKeyPath {
    var keyPath: String {
        let me = String(describing: self)
        let dropLeading =  "\\" + String(describing: Root.self) + "."
        let keyPath = "\(me.dropFirst(dropLeading.count))"
        return keyPath
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. String(describing: self) returns a description on Value type instead of keyPathName

Comment: This will break if your model is in a module, or uses a WritableKeyPath instead of a regular KeyPath.

Answer (score 1):

I created this extension for getting property names. Also works as part of packages.

```
extension KeyPath {
    var propertyAsString: String {
        "\(self)".components(separatedBy: ".").last ?? ""
    }
}
```