# Print variable name in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, printing, variable-names

I have a global variable like:

```
let myVar:Bool = true
```

I want to get the actual name (as `String`) of the variable. Something like:

```
print(myVar.name)
```

should print the `myVar` string.

**Note**: I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005654/get-a-swift-variables-actual-name-as-string/37818679#37818679) but it does not deal with global variables. It will only work with classes & structs it seems.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't just create something like that:  let myVarString: String = "myVar" ?
Why do you need this feature ?

Comment: Maybe this topic will be useful for you: [C# equivalence of "name of" in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891310/is-there-a-swift-equivalent-of-cs-nameof-function-to-get-a-variable-or-mem?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @damdamo Sadly, reflection concept will only work with class objects :(

Comment: In which context do you need it ? Do you have an example ?