# Get codable's property names as strings in swift

Tags: swift, object, firebase-realtime-database, struct, codable

#### Edit

`let disucssionMessageTimestampKey = DiscussionMessage.CodingKeys.messageTimestamp.stringValue` gives an error:

`'CodingKeys' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level`

---

I have a message structure defined like this:

```
struct DiscussionMessage: Codable {
    let message, userCountryCode, userCountryEmoji, userName, userEmailAddress: String
    let messageTimestamp: Double
    let fcmToken, question, recordingUrl, profilePictureUrl: String?
}
```

I want to define a variable `disucssionMessageTimestampKey` whose value will be `messageTimestamp`. I want to use `disucssionMessageTimestampKey` variable in the following query:

```
messagesReference.queryOrdered(byChild: "messageTimestamp").queryStarting(atValue: NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970).observe(.childAdded)
```

So that I don't have to hardcode the string value ("messageTimestamp") of the variable name.

Now I know I could just do `let disucssionMessageTimestampKey: String = "messageTimestamp"`. But this is again prone to errors. So I was wondering if there was a way that  I could get the string value `messageTimestamp` without having to define it anywhere.

By something like this (I know this won't work but just to give an idea of what I am looking for)

```
let disucssionMessageTimestampKey: String = String(describing: DiscussionMessage.messageTimestamp) // Will store disucssionMessageTimestampKey = "messageTimestamp"
```

---

Also, would it be possible to completely define the key values first as strings and then use those as variable names in the actual codable object? I.e. first define `let disucssionMessageTimestampKey: String = "messageTimestamp"`, and then use the variable `disucssionMessageTimestampKey` to define what the property (messageTimestamp) of the codable object should be called.   (This is low priority but curious and seems related to the question at hand)

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`nameof`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891310/is-there-a-swift-equivalent-of-cs-nameof-function-to-get-a-variable-or-mem)?

Comment: The question is actually related to Firebase. Maybe you could extend it to accept key paths rather than strings.

Comment: What will `DiscussionMessage.CodingKeys.messageTimestamp.stringValue` return?

Comment: what does that mean @vadian

Comment: I mean a syntax like `messagesReference.queryOrdered(byChild: \DiscussionMessage.messageTimestamp)`

Comment: that won't need an explicit "messageTimestamp" key then?

Comment: Yes, but this requires that Firebase can be extended to accept key paths.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Firebase

Comment: Any luck on this? @parth

Comment: @MasterStroke nope :/